# iOS -Keep original image when creating a loop of Core Image Filters

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimageview, core-image

I followed these 2 tutorials [tutsplus](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-apply-photo-filters-with-core-image-in-swift--cms-27142) and [appcoda](https://www.appcoda.com/core-image-introduction/)

I have an image inside vc1 that I pass to vc2. vc2 has two imageViews: `originalImageView` which shows the original image from vc1 and `filteredImageView` which shows the new image with core image filters applied. `filteredImageView` is anchored on top of `originalImageView`

I also have a scrollView that I create the coreImage filters with as buttons, once you press a button the new filter is applied and the filtered image is now shown inside the `filteredImageView` which hides the `originalImageView` since it's underneath of it.

Once a user presses any of the buttons that contain the filter, they have no way of getting back to the original image.

**How can I create a button that shows the original image inside the scrollView that goes along with all the filtered images? Ideally it would be the very first image so that once the user presses it, the original image is shown**

```
let originalImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return imageView
}()

let filteredImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return imageView
}()

let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .black
    return scrollView
}()

var originalImage: UIImage? // set from vc1

let ciFilterNames = [
    "CISharpenLuminance",
    "CIPhotoEffectChrome",
    "CIPhotoEffectFade",
    "CIPhotoEffectInstant",
    "CIPhotoEffectNoir",
    "CIPhotoEffectProcess",
    "CIPhotoEffectTonal",
    "CIPhotoEffectTransfer",
    "CISepiaTone"
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createAnchors()

    guard let originalImage = originalImage else { return }

    originaImage.image = originalImage

    var xCoord: CGFloat = 5
    let yCoord: CGFloat = 5
    let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 70
    let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 70
    let gapBetweenButtons: CGFloat = 5

    var itemCount = 0

    for i in 0..<ciFilterNames.count {

        itemCount = i

        let filterButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: xCoord, y: yCoord, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
        filterButton.tag = itemCount
        filterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(filterButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        filterButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        filterButton.clipsToBounds = true

        guard let openGLContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES3) else { return }
        let context = CIContext(eaglContext: openGLContext)

        // Create filters for each button
        let coreImage = CIImage(image: originalImage)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "\(ciFilterNames[i])" )
        filter?.setDefaults()
        filter?.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        if ciFilterNames[i] == "CISharpenLuminance" {
            filter?.setValue(0.8, forKey: kCIInputSharpnessKey)
        } else {
            filter?.setValue(1, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
        }

        guard let output = filter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage else { return }
        guard let cgimgresult = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) else { return }
        let imageForButton = UIImage(cgImage: cgimgresult)
        filterButton.setBackgroundImage(imageForButton, for: .normal)

        // Add Buttons in the Scroll View
        xCoord += buttonWidth + gapBetweenButtons
        scrollView.addSubview(filterButton)
    }
}

@objc fileprivate func filterButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let button = sender as UIButton

    filteredImageView.image = button.backgroundImage( for: .normal)
}

func createAnchors() {

    view.addSubview(originalImageView)
    view.addSubview(filteredImageView)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    originalImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    originalImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    originalImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    originalImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width).isActive = true
    originalImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width).isActive = true

    filteredImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    filteredImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: originalImageView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    filteredImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: originalImageView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    filteredImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: originalImageView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: originalImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
}
```

[image: rendition]

Comment: You don't need to have two overlapping image views. Instead you may have a single image view and keep two images. To change current image use 'image' property of the UIImageView

Comment: makes sense, but how do i get back to the original image once a filter is applied and the users wants to get back to it?

Comment: store the original image in a var and set it back when you want to reset

Comment: @Sh_Khan the problem is the original image isn't shown along with the filters. I can adda barButtonItem that will revert it back when pressed but it seems like strange ux as opposed to showing the original image along with the filtered images. Btw good idea to keep the original image in a completely separate property

Comment: About scrolling. Try UITableView where each image is a cell.

Comment: 'how do i get back to the original image'. As I said, you need to keep two images. See Sh-Knan's answer

Comment: I was thinking about a horizontal collectionView and wondered maybe there was a way to include it in the scrollView. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I guess, collection view has a built-in  horizontal scroller. Otherwise, use UIScrollView as a parent of collection view.

Comment: collectionVIew has a built in horizontal scroller, it's easy to use. I should've used that instead of the scrollView and just added the original image as the first cell.

Comment: @cyanide btw good idea to just swap out the imageView's image instead of using 2 imageViews. I have to rebuild this all over again 8(

Comment: @cyanide I updated the answer with a collectionView and 1 imageView, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a scrollView I used a horizontal collectionView and inside viewDidLoad 1st I added the image from vc1 to an array of `[UIImages]` then 2nd I loop through all of the ciFilterNames and added them into the array the same way I added them to the scrollView. Doing it this way let me have the orignal image as the first image along with all of the filtered images together inside the collectionVIew. I also only needed one imageView.

I added the two steps in the comments inside viewDidLoad

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView!

let originalImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return imageView
}()

var originalImage: UIImage? // set from vc1 or just use your own UIImage(named: "whatever") for this example
var tableData = [UIImage]()
let filterCell = "filterCell"

let ciFilterNames = [
    "CISharpenLuminance",
    "CIPhotoEffectChrome",
    "CIPhotoEffectFade",
    "CIPhotoEffectInstant",
    "CIPhotoEffectNoir",
    "CIPhotoEffectProcess",
    "CIPhotoEffectTonal",
    "CIPhotoEffectTransfer",
    "CISepiaTone"
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureCollectionView()
    createAnchors()

    guard let originalImage = originalImage else { return }

    originaImage.image = originalImage

    // 1. this appends the originalImage as the very first cell
    tableData.append(originaImage)

    guard let openGLContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES3) else { return }
    let context = CIContext(eaglContext: openGLContext)

    for i in 0..<ciFilterNames.count {

        let coreImage = CIImage(image: tableData[0])
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "\(ciFilterNames[i])" )
        filter?.setDefaults()
        filter?.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        if ciFilterNames[i] == "CISharpenLuminance" {
            filter?.setValue(0.8, forKey: kCIInputSharpnessKey)
        } else if ciFilterNames[i] == "CISepiaTone" {
            filter?.setValue(1, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
        } else {
            filter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
        }

        guard let output = filter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage else { return }
        guard let cgimgresult = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) else { return }
        let newImageWithFilterApplied = UIImage(cgImage: cgimgresult)

        // 2. after each loop append the newImageWithFilterApplied to the rest of the cells
        tableData.append(newImageWithFilterApplied)
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

func configureCollectionView() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .black
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.register(FilterCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: filterCell)
}

func createAnchors() {

    view.addSubview(originalImageView)
    view.addSubview(collectionView)

    originalImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    originalImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    originalImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    originalImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width).isActive = true

    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: originalImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: filterCell, for: indexPath) as! FilterCell

    cell.imageView.image = tableData[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? FilterCell else { return }
    guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

    originalImageView.image = tableData[indexPath.item]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question (way too often people don't realize you can and *should). I'll gladly upvote it if you provide some code. (I actually did at one time have a scroll view but since mine needs were "original/final" I used a segmented control instead.)

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. I’m self taught and after yrs of learning I realize that there’s someone out there in this world who’s going to run into this problem. I’ve gotten plenty of help on SO so I want to give back. I’ll upload the code later tonight then message you. Were your needs the same as mines and how did you use a segmented control for all of those filters? Seems only possible with iPad or landscape mode.

Comment: @dfd I added the code, you can just c+p but add a collectionViewCell, name it FilterCell and add in an imageView. Also don't forget to provide an actual image for the originalImage or the guard statement will return in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I really shouldn't post comments without spell-checking! :-) Anyways, my needs were simpler - before/after on a single filter/kernel I created. While I've worked for 35 years coding, it was my first app using iOS and `UIKit` so at first I used a scroll view & page control before realizing how much better a segmented control would be. I almost needed something similar for my newest app - I was considering using thumbnail images but so far think that's better for a later release. May I add two *performance* criticisms? Based on your code posted....

Comment: (1) Find a way to use *only* one `CIContext`. I see you are creating one in a loop. It can be easily shared and is *VERY* costly to create. (2) Consider looking into getting your `CIImages` in a different thread than the main one. I honestly do not know if that is possible, but if/when I wish to create between 12-57 thumbnails for a table view I'll find out. BONUS: (3) If you haven't already found out, when using CoreImage on the iOS simulator, understand how *extremely* poor the performance is. If you wish to see real-life performance is, use an actual device. All told, your code looks good.

Comment: @dfd hey thanks for the compliments and advice. I only use a real device for testing so I haven’t seen any performance issues. If you read my question there are 2 links to 2 tutorials I used to create the cicontext and neither used a different thread. I’m unsure if it is or isn’t necessary? Here’s a video on it also, I haven’t watched it yet https://youtu.be/j3VtUKucYSw. If you need any help message me and I’ll assist you the best I can. Congrats on your 1st iOS! What’s the name? I’ll download it. Also, I think using OpenGL takes care of the heavy lifting. It’s explained in the 2nd tutorial.

Comment: Also, I just reread my code, you are correct, there doesn’t seem any need for me to create the GLContext and CIContext inside the loop (neither gets mutated). I can instantiate them outside the loop before it begins. Good catch! I’ll try it out later then change the code.

Comment: My first two apps were custom `CIKernels` I wrote to create still-image photo effects. Haven't really pushed then much so sales/downloads aren't the greatest but they were learning experiences. (I'm semi-retired after 35 years in IT.) Final thing you may need to work on someday - Apple deprecated OpenGL (!!!) in WWDC 2018 as of iOS 12. They are pushing Metal and MTKViews. The only thing I haven't (yet) gotten working is "warp" and "general" kernels, something that shouldn't affect you. But the way you create your `CIContext`, which is how I do also, will need to change someday.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I’ll look into both of them down the line. Interestingly I’m using the latest XCode and I didn’t get any warnings about OpenGL being deprecated

Comment: You was correct about the cicontext inside the loop, I moved it outside and it works fine. I updated my answer. Thanks :)